# how to display the results in the press before his buttoon.. Android

Tags: android

I'm still just learning programming in Guided please .. i want to know how where I show results textView4 multiplication in me before I press the button for a multiplicative

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView,textView4;
EditText editText;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MasukkanNilai);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hasildaributton);
    textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
 //textview4 I want to show the result of the multiplication before I press the button How where do I?

    Button();
}




public void Button(){
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hasildaributton);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MasukkanNilai);

    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer resultAmount = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                    Integer perhitunganResult = resultAmount * 13400;
                    textView.setText(perhitunganResult.toString());
                }
            }
    );

}
```

(solved..)

Comment: How do you plan on showing the result before doing the math?

Comment: Using SO as a debugger for your small program is not a good idea. What have you done to solve this?

Comment: keep what I have to do .. please guide me .. I really need guidance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to see what your application is trying to do. It looks like, and I'm going to assume, it multiplies whatever integer is entered into the EditText by 13400.

You'll need to add a text change listener to the EditText so you can keep track of whatever integer is entered.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // we don't need this method
    }

    @Override    
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // we don't need this method
    }

    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // check that the length of the text entered is greater than 0
        // this is needed because this method is still called when backspace is pressed.
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            try {
                int result = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                int perhitunganResult = result * 13400;

                // ints can be cast to Strings shorthand as so
                textView4.setText("" + perhitunganResult);

            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // something went wrong.
                // in the XML for the EditText you can set the input type to "number"
                // android:inputType="number"
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Not related to the question but since you are learning, convention for method names in java is camelCase.

Button() should be button()

Comment: Thank you very much has guided me .. solved

Comment: No problem :). Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your question.

Comment: Yes, of course... sorry if I may ask for your email .. maybe next time if I have a complicated problem can ask for help you .. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [text watcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to listen to your TextEdit and then change the value of your TextView while edited.

Comment: I've read his statement .. but I still do not know what I'm doing .. please guide me about this.. Sorry to bother